# Returning Boolean value error when traversing a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, for-loop

I am trying to find if a list is a strictly increasing sequenced if 1 and only 1 element from it is removed.  This works for some lists but does not work for others when there isn't any apparent difference between the lists.  And for large lists, it exceeds the execution time limit.  This is my code:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):

    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        new_seq = sequence.copy()
        del new_seq[i]

        if all(i < j for i, j in zip(new_seq, new_seq[1:])):
            output = True
        else:
            output = False

    return output
```

I'm creating a copy of the input list.  Then, I'm removing the element `i` and then returning `True` or `False` depending on whether the list is a strictly increasing sequence.  I am creating the copy of the list inside the for-loop to make sure that I am removing only one element.  These are some of the test runs where the code does not return the appropriate value:

```
Input:
sequence: [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output: false
Expected Output: true

Input:
sequence: [1, 2, 5, 3, 5]
Output: false
Expected Output: true
```

And in this test case, the code exceeds the execution time limit:

```
Input:
sequence: [-9996, -9995, -9994, -9993, -9991, -9989, -9987, -9986, -9985, -9983, -9982, -9980, -9978, -9977, -9976, -9975, -9974, -9972, -9968, -9966, -9965, -9961, -9957, -9956, -9955, -9954, -9952, -9948, -9942, -9939, -9938, -9936, -9935, -9932, -9931, -9927, -9925, -9923, -9922, -9921, -9920, -9919, -9918, -9908, -9905, -9902, -9901, -9900, -9899, -9897, -9896, -9894, -9888, -9886, -9880, -9878, -9877, -9876, -9874, -9872, -9871, -9870, -9869, -9868, -9867, -9865, -9857, -9856, -9855, -9854, -9853, -9852, -9851, -9849, -9848, -9846, -9845, -9843, -9842, -9841, -9840, -9837, -9834, -9828, -9826, -9824, -9823, -9820, -9816, -9814, -9812, -9811, -9810, -9809, -9807, -9806, -9804, -9803, -9801, -9800]
Output: undefined
Expected Output: false
```

Comment: The performance issue is likely due to the choice of algorithm, not the program itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the value of the last check, i.e. when you remove the last item in the list. Change it to return `True` in the first match or `False` if nothing matched

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):

    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        new_seq = sequence.copy()
        del new_seq[i]

        if all(i < j for i, j in zip(new_seq, new_seq[1:])):
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve ethe execution time limit problem.

Comment: @OnurOzbek Are you running it on some online tool by any chance?

Comment: @OnurOzbek I'm not familiar with it, but online compilers usually have few seconds time limit, although this should take less than a second to run. Is there additional code?

Comment: Nope. This is all there is.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop will always overwrite (with returning False or True) the previous result in each iteration. So it actually "forgets" about any violation in the previous iteration. Only the last iteration determines the output, so your algorithm is wrong.

Secondly, even if you would fix that error (by *exiting* the loop if the new list is not sorted), this algorithm represents a time complexity of *O(n²)*, because in *each* iteration:

- a copy of the list is made with `.copy()`
- a `del` is performed, requiring a shift of all values that follow it
- a new copy of the list is made with `new_seq[1:]`
- `zip` is called, creating yet another list
- `all` is called, iterating that new list

All of these actions are killing the performance.

Instead you should only perform *one* iteration over the list, and solve the problem without any nested iterations. One clue is that you don't actually have to *perform* the removal of the element. You only need to check the situation *as if it were* removed.

An efficient algorithm only needs to look at three values: the currently iterated value, and the two preceding values. If those three are not in order, you can determine which one should be removed, but only represent that removal in those three variables (keep the list untouched):

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    beforePrev = prev = float('-inf')
    allowExceptions = True

    for curr in sequence:
        if curr <= prev: # Order is not maintained:
            if not allowExceptions: # It's not the first time
                return False 
            allowExceptions = False
            # Decide whether to skip the current or previous value
            if curr > beforePrev:
                prev = curr;
        else: # Normal case: keep track of two preceding values
            beforePrev, prev = prev, curr
    return True
```

### Explanation

Three list values are kept in separate memory during the traversal of the list: `curr`, `prev` and `beforePrev`. The latter two lag behind the `curr` value. So at each iteration, `curr` gets the current list value, and at the end of the iteration, we shift the values: `beforePrev ← prev ← curr`. So essentially, these three values correspond to the 3 most recently visited values -- at least when there is no anomaly in the list.

So let's say at a certain moment you find an anomaly: you find a position where `curr <= prev`, i.e. where the sequence is not strictly increasing; then it is clear one of the values has to be removed: either `curr` or `prev` should be removed to have any hope that the list can be "fixed".

It could be that the algorithm had already decided that a value had to be removed at an *earlier* iteration (`allowExceptions` is `False`): but we are only allowed to remove *one* value from the list, so in that case we decide that there is no solution and return `False`

But if this was the first time we got into this situation, then we should decide whether to identify `curr` or `prev` as offending value. We may assume that `beforePrev` and `prev` are in the correct order (we verified that in the preceding iteration), so there really are only two possibilities left for the relative ordering of `beforePrev` `prev` and `curr`: either `curr > beforePrev`, or not.

If `curr > beforePrev`, then those two are placed in a good ordering relative to each other, so if we would remove `prev` from between those two, we would restore that part of the list into an increasing ordering.

If `curr <= beforePrev`, then they are not in a good ordering relative to each  other, so we should remove `curr` to restore the increasing ordering.

To save time we will not actually *perform* the removal of the chosen item from the list: we will just apply the result of that removal to the variables `beforePrev`, `prev`, and `curr`, so that in the next iteration they have values as if the list had one item removed:

As we removed an element, `beforePrev` should remain the same in the next iteration of the loop: so we don't touch its value, like we would normally do.

If we remove `prev`, then the new `prev` becomes what `curr` is now. If we remove `curr`, there is nothing to do: `prev` also remains the same for the next iteration, and `curr` will get its new value any way at the start of the next iteration.

Because we "deleted" an item we also set `allowExceptions` to `False`, so that we know that we are not allowed to perform a second deletion.

Remains to say that at the first iteration, we don't really have a `beforePrev` and `prev`, so we set them to -infinity, so that in a first iteration there will be no decision to delete yet.

Comment: I agree with your approach but I don't understand your code at all..

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer. Let me know if this clarifies it for you. Note that your original code (and the one in the other answer) will spend too much time to be a valid solution. On larger inputs they will time out.